# Can we select which object to return from serializer[many=true] based on condition

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, backend

Lets suppose i have a model Post with field such as

```
Model Post
- Name :  TextField
- Body : TextField
- isPrivate : Boolean
```

Now the query `post_obj = Post.objects.all()` return 10 objects which is passed to getPostDataSerializer()

```
class getPostDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    permission_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Galaxy
        fields =  ("Name","Body","permission_set")
    def get_permission_set():
        permissions = some_other_serializer_which_gives_us_permission().data
        return set(permissions)
```

we have

```
post_data = getPostDataSerializer(post_obj,many=True).data
```

which returns name, body and permission_set of all 10 objects but i want to receive data of only those posts which have certain permissions which is extracted in serializer itself

Please help

Comment: If I understood your problem correctly you can filter queryset based on isPrivate field: `post_data = getPostDataSerializer(post_obj.filter(isPrivate=False),many=True).data`

Comment: I want a method to filter data from the serializer side itself, because of NDA I can't really share the entirety of code but what I am doing is calling another serializer to get permission data for each object and i want serializer to return only the data with some specific permission, apologies for misleading question let me edit and clarify it a bit better

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll have to filter the posts by the `isActive` field by doing: `public_posts = Post.objects.filter(isPrivate=False)`

Then you can pass it on to the serializer

```
post_data = getPostDataSerializer(public_posts,many=True).data
```

Comment: I want a method to filter data from the serializer side itself, because of NDA I can't really share the entirety of code but what I am doing is calling another serializer to get permission data for each object and i want serializer to return only the data with some specific permission, apologies for misleading question let me edit and clarify it a bit better